# Ubuntu File system / Partition / Dual boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hp

I am new to Ubuntu.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my hp laptop along with Windows 7.
I had already installed win7 and I was trying to install Ubuntu.

First - option "**Install alongside with win 7**" was missing.

So O chose "**Something else**" and there I can see 2 drives already there created by Windows.

Now when I am trying to create more partition on Ubuntu architecture I am not able to create more that 2 drives or partition. After that the unallocated space (free space) goes UNUSABLE (I have 800gigs of free as my laptop has got 1 tb hdd).

So I want to know:

1.How many partition can be created on Ubuntu architecture?

2.How can I create more than 2 partition **(swap, / , /boot, and /home )**?

3. Is it important to create these **(swap, / , /boot, and /home )** .
   partitions to install Ubuntu or can I install Ubuntu without creating them?

4.What are the maximum number of drives which can be created in Ubuntu.

Also if there is comprehensive guide to learn Ubuntu please share the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many partitions you may have per disk does not depend on Ubuntu, but the partition table type you use on that disk.

There are two types, `msdos` is the old one, sometimes also called `MBR` (master boot record). It only allows disk sizes up to 2TB and only 4 primary partitions. The other, new type is `GPT` ("GUID Partition Table"), which allows up to about 9ZB (9×10²¹ Bytes, unimaginably huge) for the disk size and allows 128 primary partitions.

You obviously have a `msdos`-partitioned disk, so you may only create 4 primary partitions on it.

But you could delete one of your 4 primary partitions and create an **extended partition** instead. This is not a partition you can format and use to store data directly, but it is like a container for **logical volumes/partitions**. You can create an infinite amount of logical volumes that behave like partitions to the OS inside this extended partition.

---

On a normal Ubuntu installation, you only need `/` (file system root, format as `ext4`), but it is very highly recommended to also create a `swap` partition (format as `linux-swap`) too. It should have about 1-2 times your RAM size, but that is a discussion itself...

If you want, it can also be useful to use a separate `/home` partition (format as `ext4`). It will hold all your user data and settings. Otherwise, it is included in `/`, but having it in a separate partition might make creating backups or reinstalling Ubuntu without losing your data and settings easier.

As you dual-boot with Windows, you might also want to create a small (few GBs!) transfer partition to be able to copy data from one OS to the other. Use `FAT32` as file system for this, because if you chose `NTFS`, you might get permission problems. This might be needed because Windows can't access the `ext4` partitions Ubuntu uses and needs. However, you may access Windows' `NTFS` partitions from inside Ubuntu anyway.

Comment: If this answers all your questions, don't forget to accept it (click the grey tick symbol on the left of this answer). You may leave me a comment if anything remained unclear otherwise. Also please take the 2-minutes [tour] of askubuntu, if you haven't already done so, to learn about how this site works. Thank you and welcome! :-)

Comment: thanks for the answer 

1.Please suggest which should be the primary partition
(swap, / , /boot, and /home )??

2.How i can created an extended partition or creating logical partition is known as extended partition ?

3.if i will make all logical patition then, will i be able to create more that 2 partitions? 

4.Also if i will make all logical patition then, will i be able to install ubuntu and will it work perfectly fine?

Comment: You can install Ubuntu on either primary or logical partitions, it doesn't matter. Windows and other OS however require at least their boot partition to be primary, I think, but not sure if this is still the case today. So you can just make all partitions for Ubuntu logical if you want. I don't remember how the installer looked like, but if you only may chose between primary and logical, choosing logical automatically wraps it into an extended partition, as they may not exist outside one. Note that there may be only one extended partition, so the logical ones need to be next to each other.

Comment: **Reviewer note:** As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer that worked, i was able to created multiple partition but logical. However after completing the installation on ubuntu 14.04 when i rebooted i am getting a error - no bootable media found please insert bootable media and press any key".... any suggestions on this . i have installed ubuntu on /boot directory also win 7 was already installed (working properly) seems that is gone too !!!!

Comment: Where did you select to install the boot loader? You have to install it directly to the disk, not to a partition (e.g. to `sda` and not `sda5`). And if you did not touch the Windows partitions during the installation, they should be still alive. You're probably just not having a working boot loader at the moment.