# EFI System Partition and its significance

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I am installing Ubuntu as dual boot with win 7 already installed 
Partition table type - MBR

Is it important to create EFI system partition

If yes, then should the EFI system partition be primary or secondary?

What is a EFI system partition and what is its significance ?

Comment: The ESP - efi system partition is for UEFI boot on gpt partitioned drives. If hardware is BIOS only then you do not need an efi partition. And Windows only boots from MBR partitioned drives with BIOS, so Ubuntu must also be installed in BIOS mode. With new UEFI systems all systems install boot loader files into separate folders in the ESP. With BIOS only one system has control of MBR. So the ESP is somewhat like having mulitple MBR, but on one drive.

Answer (score 5):

When Windows is installed in Legacy BIOS (MBR) mode you do not need to create an EFI partition. When Windows is installed in UEFI mode you already do have an EFI partition.
Then you have to install ubuntu in UEFI mode - the existing EFI partition will be used.

Learn more : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 2):

1. Is it important to create EFI system partition for partition table type MBR?

**No.** Generally computers that came with partition table type MBR have BIOS. Newer computers that come with partition table type GPT, also come with UEFI instead of BIOS. If this is true for your computer, then your computer has BIOS and not UEFI. If there is no UEFI, there is no need for EFI system partition, as a part of UEFI goes into the EFI system partition. So, only computers with UEFI must have EFI system partition.

2. If yes, then EFI system partition should be primary or secondary?

The EFI system partition should be **primary**. In partition table type GPT, all partitions are primary, is this type of partition table can have many more than four primary partitions. If you do need to create an EFI System partition in a MBR, the partition should have the ID 0xEF.

3. What is an EFI system partition and what its significance?

The new computers don't have a BIOS, but have UEFI, **United Extensible Firmware Interface**. The Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) needs a partition called EFI System partition (**ESP**).

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition): **ESP** contains the boot loader programs for all installed operating systems (which are contained in other partitions on the same or other storage device), device driver files for devices present in a computer that are used by the firmware at boot time, system utility programs that are intended to be run before an operating system is booted, and data files such as error logs.

**Note:** If your computer came with UEFI and GPT, and you changed the UEFI to Legacy/CSM/BIOS mode, before installing Windows 7, then you should install Ubuntu in the same mode. In this case you will not need the ESP partition. You may delete it or **keep it if you want to revert back the UEFI mode for some reason.** See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI for more on UEFI.

*From [oldfred's](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred) comments:*

You can install Windows 7 in UEFI mode but have to copy to flash drive and move some files around. And if you install Windows 7 in BIOS mode to a gpt drive it converts drive to MBR, but does not do it correctly. It leaves the backup gpt partition table, so Linux sees both MBR & gpt. Since it does not know what you want, the only choice is to start over. But you can remove the backup gpt data with [fixparts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/). But to fully utilize new hardware installing in UEFI mode is better.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks alot for this very very useful information. here i wanna know .

i am trying to make dual boot on my laptop however i am facing some issues

how many partition i need to create while installing ubuntu (swap, / , /boot, EFI and /home ) minimum requirement ?? 

My laptop model is HP-2313AX (dos based) if you wanna know about hardware details 

I have installed win 7 on a 50 gigs partition and left around 900gigs unallocated 

kindly check 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/662214/ubuntu-file-system-partition-dual-boot

Comment: I feel my laptop is a UEFI based architecture, however i have enabled legacy boot option so that in can install win7 . else its not even allowing me to install win7 and will support win 8 and above.

though i have converted hdd in mbr from diskpart and i wasnt able to see partiton in ubuntu if i partition under GPT

Comment: The answer is updated.

Comment: You can install Windows 7 in UEFI mode but have to copy to flash drive and move some files around. And if you install Windows 7 in BIOS mode to a gpt drive it converts drive to MBR, but does not do it correctly. It leaves the backup gpt partition table, so Linux sees both MBR & gpt. Since it does not know what you want, the only choice is to start over. But you can remove the backup gpt data with fixparts. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/ But to fully utilize new hardware installing in UEFI mode is better.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you very much for this comment. If you don't mind, I will add this comment to my answer.